# How to change inflation rate of a substrate based chain?

Tags: polkadot, rewards

I want to change inflation rate of a substrate based chain, the method for inflation is written in `frame/staking/reward-curve` and it being initialised in `bin/node/runtime/lib.rs`

```
pallet_staking_reward_curve::build! {
    const REWARD_CURVE: PiecewiseLinear<'static> = curve!(
        min_inflation: 0_025_000,
        max_inflation: 0_100_000,
        ideal_stake: 0_500_000,
        falloff: 0_050_000,
        max_piece_count: 40,
        test_precision: 0_005_000,
    );
}
```

So i changed the `min_inflation and max_inflation` in runtime/lib.rs but the inflation rate does change. What I want to ask is am I doing something wrong or is it not the right way to change the inflation rate.

Comment: good question bro

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the right way. That's what the pallet wants you to do.

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const RewardCurve: &'static PiecewiseLinear<'static> = &REWARD_CURVE;
}


impl pallet_staking::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type EraPayout = pallet_staking::ConvertCurve<RewardCurve>;
}
```

As you can see, the trait name is `Config`. So this is a configuration for you.

You may write your pallet in the future. And if you want other people to use the pallet more flexibly. You would also provide some configurations.

Comment: Thats what i thought but when i changed and built it, there was no change at all in inflation.

Comment: Did you clean the DB or make a runtime upgrade? What chain are you using? Or you should re `build-sepc`.

Comment: Just build a new substrate chain and run it in development mode with inflation changes but it is not reflecting.

Comment: May I have your code?

Comment: It is a substrate clone just changed the value of min_inflation and max_inflation